# Dockerfile for multiple Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working with Docker and I have a web-app that requires the following:

1. Tomcat
2. PostgreSQL
3. MongoDB

To install item 2 and 3 I do the following:

I can run a command for PostgreSQL like :

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

For Mongodb I run:

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo
```

For Tomcat, I have a Dockerfile with Tomcat and copying my war to the apps folder.  I build the image using Docker and run it.

My question is whether there is a better way to coordinate this step by step via separate script?  Is Docker compose the solution for this?

thanks

Comment: `docker-compose` is meant for exactly this sort of situation.  You should try it out and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically docker-compose is just a yaml file implementation of docker run.
As docker run has arguments passed to it, these exact same arguments are stipulated in docker compose in a yaml format instead of on the command line.
Docker compose supports multiple containers too.

Docker compose has a few other nice features such as docker-compose logs , this command gives logs of all containers started by compose.

Answer (score 13):

A Dockerfile is a recipe for building an image, which is a template for starting containers.  To describe a system that is made of multiple containers using standardized images, you would use docker-compose, not a  new Dockerfile.  You would use a Dockerfile to customize a pre-existing docker image, like mysql or node or ubuntu, for some specific use.

[`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) allows you to express multiple docker commands as a .yml file in a specific format.

You can then use `docker-compose up` to start the set of containers.

The [docker-compose .yml file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)  for your example might start looking somewhat like this

```
some-postgres:
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD:mysecretpassword
    image: postgres

some-mongo:
    image: mongo
```

You would add links between the containers with a `links:` line.  These and other details are in the docs.